# Remove \" from javascript string

Tags: javascript, xml, string, back, backslash

I dont want to escape the double quote `"` character. Xml parser is giving me an error with a xml string with backslashes inside the xml tags.

I want to convert this `\"param\"` into this `"param"`.

Any solutions?.

-Sorry i've put the wrong symbol, now its ok.

**SOLUTION**

This is the final solution.

```
string.replace(/\"/g, '')
```

Comment: You should post the actual XML that's causing the problems.

Answer (score 0):

```
var st =  '/"param/" ';
alert(st.split('/').join(''))
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var txt = '/"param/"';
txt = txt.replace(/\//g,"");
```